# Qt - How to specify and make constant an element size in a layout?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, geometry

Say there is a QHBoxLayout and some widgets in it. How to specify a widget width and hight in the layout, so that while resizing the widget which containes the layout the given width and hight stay constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
void QWidget::setFixedSize ( int w, int h )
```

which Sets the width of the widget to w and the height to h. This will make the size of the particular widget fixed when the window is re-sized.

Also you can use the combination of these functions,

```
void QWidget::setFixedHeight ( int h )
```

and also

```
void QWidget::setFixedWidth ( int w )
```

whichever is required for your need.. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

One (simple) way to do this is to use QWidget::setMinimumSize and QWidget::setMaximumSize functions to set minimum size and maximum size to be the same. Doing this will prevent widget from expanding and shrinking. E.g.

```
widget->setMinimumSize( 200, 100 );
widget->setMaximumSize( 200, 100 );
```

Of course you can set these values in QtDesigner also.

Comment: This is what I used. But I have asked for another kind of solution (may be a better one).